# I'm copying data from my database, how do I know which tables to copy from first to avoid reference errors?

Tags: sql, database, insert, sql-insert

I have a database schema which has numerous tables and relationships between tables - you know, the standard SQL database setup.

I want to generate `insert` statements to "copy" the data from one database to another which has the same schema, but none of the data.

The problem is that if I do this in any order, it might not work since data being inserted first might depend on data which doesn't get scripted until later.

How can I order the `insert` statements so the data dependencies are in the correct order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort you want is known as a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). This orders elements (in your case, tables) so that depending elements come after dependency elements. One common technique to perform this kind of sorting is to build a [graph structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) and apply the sorting algorithm on it. Many frameworks have libraries which build graphs and have algorithms to perform the topological sort for you ([.Net](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/), [Java](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht), [Python](http://networkx.github.io/), [C++](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/)).

One problem you'll face is if your tables have cyclical relationships. For example:

```
    [a] --> [b] --> [a]
```

This cycle prevents the graph from being topologically sorted, and unless you know that none of the entities in `[a]` refer to entities in `[b]` which in turn refer to the same entities in `[a]` again, you can't be certain you will avoid a referential conflict.

Here is an example script in C# (using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx)) which queries the relationships in a database schema, uses [Quickgraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) to build a graph, then topologically sorts it and lists the sorted tables (from which you can build your `insert` statements), or lists the tables with dependency cycles if it can't be topologically sorted:

http://share.linqpad.net/47qds2.linq

```
void Main()
{
    var targetDb = "MyDb";

    var relationSql = @"SELECT pk.TABLE_NAME as PrimaryKeyTable,
                            fk.TABLE_NAME as ForeignKeyRefTable
                        FROM
                            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS r
                            INNER JOIN 
                                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS fk
                            ON
                                fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = r.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                            INNER JOIN 
                                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk
                            ON
                                pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = r.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME

                        ORDER BY
                        ForeignKeyRefTable";
    var tableSql = @"select t.[object_id] as TableId, t.[name] as TableName, c.[name] as ColName
                    from sys.tables t
                        inner join sys.columns c
                        on t.object_id = c.object_id";

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog={0}", targetDb)))
    {
        var tables = conn.Query<Table>(tableSql);
        var relations = conn.Query<Relation>(relationSql);
        var relationGraph = new QuickGraph.AdjacencyGraph<String, Edge<String>>();
        relationGraph.AddVertexRange(tables.Select(t => t.TableName));
        var relationEdges = from r in relations
                            where r.ForeignKeyRefTable != r.PrimaryKeyTable
                            select new QuickGraph.Edge<String>(r.PrimaryKeyTable, r.ForeignKeyRefTable);
        relationGraph.AddEdgeRange(relationEdges);

        // The graph can be topologically sorted only if it is acyclic
        if (relationGraph.IsDirectedAcyclicGraph())
        {
            var inRelationOrder = relationGraph.TopologicalSort();
            inRelationOrder.Dump("Sorted Tables");
        }
        else
        {
            var connected = AlgorithmExtensions.CondensateStronglyConnected<String, Edge<String>, AdjacencyGraph<String, Edge<String>>>(relationGraph);
            var cycles = from v in connected.Vertices
                        where v.VertexCount > 1
                        select v.Vertices;
            cycles.Dump("Dependency Cycles");
        }
    }    
}

public class Table
{
    public Int32 TableId { get; set; }
    public String TableName { get; set; }
    public String ColName{ get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public String PrimaryKeyTable { get; set; }
    public String ForeignKeyRefTable { get; set; }
}
```